# How to put quotes for all the numbers using regular expression?

Tags: regex

I have a file of just numbers all in separate line such as

```
+11234567890
+11567876788
+11234567811
+10234567823 
//... and so on
```

How can I put quotes in all the numbers using regular expression like the following 
using Visual Studio code find and replace?

```
"+11234567890"
"+11567876788"
"+11234567811"
"+10234567823"
```

Comment: `^(.*)$` with `"$1"`

Comment: Welcome to SO! What's the relvance to JS and Python? Can you share what you've tried so far? Thanks.

Comment: @ASDFGerte thank you,, that was quick reply

Comment: @ggorlen Thank you.. 
there is no relevance to python and javascript, but i will be using either python or javascript for furthur use..

Comment: I think most straight forward way to do this is `^.*$` with `"$&"`, but as usually capture groups are necessary, my brain always thinks about these first. Doesn't really matter anyways.

Answer (score 3):

I am assuming you are using NodeJS for this or Python3

Node

```js
const readline = require('readline');
const fs = require('fs');

// Initialize readInterface
const readInterface = readline.createInterface({
  input: fs.createReadStream('/path/to/file'),
  output: process.stdout,
  console: false
});


// This gets call on everyline
readInterface.on('line', function(line) {
  var quotedLine = "\"" + line + "\"";
  fs.appendFile("/path/to/file.txt", quotedLine, (err) =>{
    if(err){console.log(err)}
  });
  console.log("Writing Line...");
});
```

Python3

```py
filepath = 'phonenumbers.txt'

# Open the file
with open(filepath) as phoneNums:
  # Get lines
  line = phoneNums.readline()

  # Iterate through all lines
  while line:
    print("Writing line")

    # Write the quoted lines to a new file
    with open("quoted.txt", 'w') as quotedNumbers:
      quotedNumbers.write("\"" + line + "\"")
```

Answer (score 1):

To make this happen you will need to:

1. Open the file
2. Read each line of the file and store each line "value" in an array
3. Write/Overwrite in a new/same file each index of the array and add to it **" + array[index] + "**. You will need to use **"** in order to had quotation marks characters. In this case \ is an escape character for the quotation mark.
4. After writting the line, jump to a new line. Use **"\n"**.
5. Close the file

**FileInputStream** on #2 and **FileOutputStream** on #3. Both with a **for cicle**

Answer (score -1):

```
f = open('file.txt', 'r')
for i in f:
  i = '"'+i+'"'
```

Comment: Well, no. `str` has no effect on strings. This won't add anything.

Comment: They are not strings, though. otherwise they would already have quotes. Also added another way to do it without needing it to be an integer.

Comment: Yes, they are. You use quotes (`'`, `"`, `"""`,`'''`) to create a string litterals in your code, but the quotes are not part of the string.

Comment: Also, note that the question explicitely states "using regular expression"

Comment: Does that mean something besides "normal expression"?

Comment: Yes, it does. See for example Python [re module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#module-re), and search for 'regular expression' or 'regex' on the web.